# Windows store 8 app - Playing files from NAS drive

Tags: c#, video, mvvm, windows-store-apps, mediaelement

Ive created a little app for the kids at home which connects to my Drobo were I have roughly 1000 movies. The app obtains all the information for these movies and stores the info in a SQLite database.

Im having trouble playing the media from the file path using the MediaElement Control.

Im using c# with MVVM, the problem I have is, most samples show you how to pick a file and play it using a stream. This is fine however I don't want the kids (2 and 5 yrs old) to have to do this each time.

In attempt to avoid this and im storing the file location in my database ie
192.168.1.3\Movies\Micky Mouse.mp4

ive created the code to set the source using a URI and binded the controls source (xaml) to the property. As you can guess the media is not playing.

If I put the media into local storage it plays fine so I know the issue is directly related to access permissions. What I have found is, if I choose the folder location and play the movie say 5mins later it will play however if I attempt this the following day the video does not play.

To me there seems to be a timed access token to the NAS drive.

Does anyone here achieve video playback outside of local storage using a URI (filepath)

Thank you for any guidance

Comment: *were I have roughly 1000 movies* sounds legit

Comment: Yes they are legit, I have an extensive DVD and Blu-ray collection over the last 10 years which have multiplied a lot over the last 6 years with my 2 kids.

On a side note, ive started building a home cinema in the garden to house this collection we're myself and my family can enjoy these.

You can pick up a dvd for less than £1 from CEX.

Id prefer to have hard copies of a Dvd/Blu rays and the digital format is purely for collection management. I even made a desktop app for this once

http://sourceforge.net/projects/movee8/?source=directory

Not everyone wants to download using torrents!

Comment: Ok so back on topic. I have come across the FutureAccessList in windows store apps which allow 1000 locations to be added. A folder, its subfolders and files are accessible however the media still isn't playing but I don't get an access permission error anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a lotta rippin' :)

Answer (score 1):

The file / folder picker is required to grant the initial permissions, once this is granted add the file to the future access list.

```
private async void ChooseFile()
    {

        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file, "Test");
        }
        else
        {
            // The file picker was dismissed with no file selected to save
        }
```

}

How to get the file and play the media

```
foreach (AccessListEntry itm in StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Entries)
            {
                if (itm.Metadata == "Test")
                {
                    StorageFile actualFile = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(itm.Token);

                    var stream = await actualFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

                    mediaPlayer.SetSource(stream, actualFile.ContentType);
                    mediaPlayer.Play();
                }
            }
```

This was a head banger of an issue im sure many folks will enjoy this solution :)

@will even though your comment want non-productive I do appreciate you having a look